# MySql Strange Runs Of Command Denied Errors

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have an intermittent problem with a MySql database.

Everything runs just fine for long periods of time, but then we suddenly get a run of errors being logged such as this:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: UPDATE command denied to user
>   'user'@'ip.add.ress' for table 'tblTable'

The user being reported is the correct user. The same user works just fine almost all the time, but when we get this error we get a load all at once.

I know this is vague, but I have checked that the permissions exist, and indeed the same code, using the same user works almost all the time.

**Confirmation**: We are not restricting access by IP - it's just a user name and password.

Comment: The IP/Host are also part of the grant rules,  is the combination of user and 'ip.add.ress' what you exepect for this table ?

Comment: Yes - good question. The IP address is consistent the whole time and it is always the same user.

Comment: does this happen during high load ? which storage engine are you using ? is it perhaps related to some parallel long-running transaction scenario ?

Comment: Not a particularly high load - it happened outside of our peak hours and there is nothing to suggest a spike of traffic at that time. We don't have any deadlocks showing and we tend to use transactions only for the shortest possible time. We are using InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one out. We solved this issue by granting the same user elevated permissions (i.e. against the MySQL instance as well as the specific database).